# How to use NodeMCU 0.9 - 12E pins D0-D4

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu

I've been trying to connect a simple sensor to any of pins D0-D4 but see values ranging all over the place. Nothing consistent to them.

Started wondering if these pins might be in use due to one of the modules included in my build. For example, I've tried hooking up a DHT11 sensor using the [NodeMCU DHT Module](http://nodemcu.readthedocs.org/en/dev/en/modules/dht/#dhtread11). I am getting the following values returned:

```
status: -2
temp: -999
humi: -999
temp_dec: 0
humi_dec: 0
```

I also tried a PIR Motion Sensor but can't get it to trigger. I haven't had any problems hooking these up on Arduinos. I'm pretty sure the physical hookup is correct.

```
S -> any of D0-D4 (don't work)
- -> Gnd
+ -> VCC 3V
```

My particular DHT11 has a 10K pullup resistor on the PCB.

One more clue that these pins are different is that I'm unable to use only D2 out of D0-D4 for my SPI OLED DC. Any of the others throw garbage on the display.

Here is a dump of my NodeMCU startup:

```
NodeMCU custom build by frightanic.com
    branch: master
    commit: c8037568571edb5c568c2f8231e4f8ce0683b883
    SSL: false
    modules: adc,bit,cjson,coap,crypto,dht,enduser_setup,file,gpio,i2c,mqtt,net,node,pwm,rtctime,spi,tmr,u8g,uart,wifi
 build  built on: 2016-02-03 23:59
 powered by Lua 5.1.4 on SDK 1.4.0
```

Can anyone confirm that any of the modules included in my build are interfering with me using D0-D4 for arbitrary use?

Or, are these pins not intended for these sensors?

Comment: Is the problem solved? Is there any more feedback you need? If not I suggest you accept the right answer so that SO can mark this question as closed, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell without you showing us the relevant pieces of your Lua code. You did get the [v1 devkit pins](http://frightanic.com/iot/comparison-of-esp8266-nodemcu-development-boards/#v1) right, did you?

If so, could it be that you don't use the proper GPIO pin mapping in Lua? They need to be mapped according to this: http://nodemcu.readthedocs.org/en/dev/en/modules/gpio/

Also, IMHO you should use a firmware with the [DHT module](http://nodemcu.readthedocs.org/en/dev/en/modules/dht/) rather than be using the DHT Lua sample script.

Comment: I did end up using the DHT module and it works. I still don't know why the LUA script wouldn't work. :S

Answer (score 1):

Bonjour
I've spent a full day to make my nodemcu work with a DHT11 sensor. The thing is the ESP8266 running with the Lua firmware is somewhat too slow for the DHT sensor, especially when the DHT sensor starts to send the first pulses. That's the conclusion I come to from this experience.

So, setting the frequency of the nodemcu to 160MHZ helped me a lot.
Cf. command "node.setcpufreq(node.CPU160MHZ)"

Browsing the forums, it seems the previous version of the firmware could also be more effective in terms of performance?
https://piandmore.wordpress.com/2016/02/05/nodemcu-onewire-problem/
I have not tried this downgrade but it could be worth to do it.

Hope that may help you.
Alain

Comment: You _are_ using a firmware with the [DHT module](http://nodemcu.readthedocs.org/en/dev/en/modules/dht/) rather than the DHT Lua sample script, right?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem while interfacing with a DHT11. I tried modifying the CPU frequency, but that didn't solve the problem. Finally i found out that the problem was with the hardware setup. I simply pulled the data pin of DHT11 to Vcc (+5V) through a 10K resistor (recommended is 5K). Since then i haven't faced any problem.